# Amazon paapi 5.0 : getting 429 error always. com.amazon.paapi5#TooManyRequestsException

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api

I am trying to fetch the data from amazon store by using amazon paapi5.0 but it always gives me error 429. which is `too many requests per second.` I tried to run this thing in amazon scratch pad but it is giving back as also same error.
Below here I am attaching the screenshot of the scratchpad error[image]

Also I am facing same problem with the implementation of the code in java script. The error and the code snippet I am attaching below please help me to resolve issue.

**The code**

```
/**
 * Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

// Run `npm install` locally before executing following code with `node sampleGetItemsApi.js`

/**
 * This sample code snippet is for ProductAdvertisingAPI 5.0's GetItems API
 * For more details, refer:
 * https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/get-items.html
 */

var ProductAdvertisingAPIv1 = require('./src/index');

var defaultClient = ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.ApiClient.instance;

// Specify your credentials here. These are used to create and sign the request.
defaultClient.accessKey = 'my access key here';
defaultClient.secretKey = 'my screte key';

/**
 * PAAPI Host and Region to which you want to send request.
 * For more details refer: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/common-request-parameters.html#host-and-region
 */
defaultClient.host = 'webservices.amazon.com';
defaultClient.region = 'us-east-1';

var api = new ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.DefaultApi();

// Request Initialization

var getItemsRequest = new ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItemsRequest();

/** Enter your partner tag (store/tracking id) and partner type */
getItemsRequest['PartnerTag'] = 'my Partner tag';
getItemsRequest['PartnerType'] = 'Associates';

/** Enter the Item IDs for which item information is desired */
getItemsRequest['ItemIds'] = ['059035342X'];

getItemsRequest['Condition'] = 'New';

/**
 * Choose resources you want from GetItemsResource enum
 * For more details, refer: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/get-items.html#resources-parameter
 */
getItemsRequest['Resources'] = ['Images.Primary.Medium', 'ItemInfo.Title', 'Offers.Listings.Price'];

/**
 * Function to parse GetItemsResponse into an object with key as ASIN
 */
function parseResponse(itemsResponseList) {
  var mappedResponse = {};
  for (var i in itemsResponseList) {
    if (itemsResponseList.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      mappedResponse[itemsResponseList[i]['ASIN']] = itemsResponseList[i];
    }
  }
  return mappedResponse;
}

function onSuccess(data) {
  console.log('API called successfully.');
  var getItemsResponse = ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItemsResponse.constructFromObject(data);
  console.log('Complete Response: \n' + JSON.stringify(getItemsResponse, null, 1));
  if (getItemsResponse['ItemsResult'] !== undefined) {
    console.log('Printing All Item Information in ItemsResult:');
    var response_list = parseResponse(getItemsResponse['ItemsResult']['Items']);
    for (var i in getItemsRequest['ItemIds']) {
      if (getItemsRequest['ItemIds'].hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var itemId = getItemsRequest['ItemIds'][i];
        console.log('\nPrinting information about the Item with Id: ' + itemId);
        if (itemId in response_list) {
          var item = response_list[itemId];
          if (item !== undefined) {
            if (item['ASIN'] !== undefined) {
              console.log('ASIN: ' + item['ASIN']);
            }
            if (item['DetailPageURL'] !== undefined) {
              console.log('DetailPageURL: ' + item['DetailPageURL']);
            }
            if (
              item['ItemInfo'] !== undefined &&
              item['ItemInfo']['Title'] !== undefined &&
              item['ItemInfo']['Title']['DisplayValue'] !== undefined
            ) {
              console.log('Title: ' + item['ItemInfo']['Title']['DisplayValue']);
            }
            if (
              item['Offers'] !== undefined &&
              item['Offers']['Listings'] !== undefined &&
              item['Offers']['Listings'][0]['Price'] !== undefined &&
              item['Offers']['Listings'][0]['Price']['DisplayAmount'] !== undefined
            ) {
              console.log('Buying Price: ' + item['Offers']['Listings'][0]['Price']['DisplayAmount']);
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log('Item not found, check errors');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if (getItemsResponse['Errors'] !== undefined) {
    console.log('\nErrors:');
    console.log('Complete Error Response: ' + JSON.stringify(getItemsResponse['Errors'], null, 1));
    console.log('Printing 1st Error:');
    var error_0 = getItemsResponse['Errors'][0];
    console.log('Error Code: ' + error_0['Code']);
    console.log('Error Message: ' + error_0['Message']);
  }
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log('Error calling PA-API 5.0!');
  console.log('Printing Full Error Object:\n' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 1));
  console.log('Status Code: ' + error['status']);
  if (error['response'] !== undefined && error['response']['text'] !== undefined) {
    console.log('Error Object: ' + JSON.stringify(error['response']['text'], null, 1));
  }
}

api.getItems(getItemsRequest).then(
  function(data) {
    onSuccess(data);
  },
  function(error) {
    onError(error);
  }
);
```

**The error response I am getting**

```
Error calling PA-API 5.0!
Printing Full Error Object:
{
 "status": 429,
 "response": {
  "req": {
   "method": "POST",
   "url": "https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/getitems",
   "data": {
    "ItemIds": [
     "059035342X"
    ],
    "PartnerTag": "zserfv45-21",
    "PartnerType": "Associates",
    "Condition": "New",
    "Resources": [
     "Images.Primary.Medium",
     "ItemInfo.Title",
     "Offers.Listings.Price"
    ]
   },
   "headers": {
    "user-agent": "paapi5-nodejs-sdk/1.0.0",
    "authorization": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIGIUBJ2E4NJEZW3A/20230423/us-east-1/ProductAdvertisingAPI/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-encoding;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=033005cd9cc72e2fce23e4d331924d0752230fd50cba07c215edd7598638974e",        
    "content-encoding": "amz-1.0",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "host": "webservices.amazon.com",
    "x-amz-target": "com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItems",
    "x-amz-date": "20230423T062343Z",
    "accept": "application/json"
   }
  },
  "header": {
   "server": "Server",
   "date": "Sun, 23 Apr 2023 06:23:45 GMT",
   "content-type": "application/json",
   "content-length": "247",
   "connection": "close",
   "x-amz-rid": "ZWZPMJFE2FGXPCBWRQQF",
   "x-amzn-requestid": "284f73c9-e2e4-4438-adc8-da2673b7bf60",
   "vary": "Content-Type,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent",
   "strict-transport-security": "max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload"
  },
  "status": 429,
  "text": "{\"__type\":\"com.amazon.paapi5#TooManyRequestsException\",\"Errors\":[{\"Code\":\"TooManyRequests\",\"Message\":\"The request was 
denied due to request throttling. Please verify the number of requests made per second to the Amazon Product Advertising API.\"}]}"
 }
}
Status Code: 429
Error Object: "{\"__type\":\"com.amazon.paapi5#TooManyRequestsException\",\"Errors\":[{\"Code\":\"TooManyRequests\",\"Message\":\"The request 
was denied due to request throttling. Please verify the number of requests made per second to the Amazon Product Advertising API.\"}]}"
```

I tried same request sending like 40-50 times but no improvement.

Comment: try connecting to your region (https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/common-request-parameters.html#host-and-region) rather than the default US (webservices.amazon.com)

Comment: @gog I tried with the india (India  webservices.amazon.in  eu-west-1) but it replies me with the same error code

Answer (score 2):

I am also having the same problem which could be caused by several factors. The first is that you may be making too many requests. In that case, the solution would be to limit the number of request and enter a sleep (3s are fine) between requests. This should fix the problem.

The second case, similar to mine, is if you haven't made any sales in the last 30 days. Amazon will not invest resources to provide you with API access if you are not generating any revenue on the platform. Ideally, if you receive a purchase from your affiliate link within 48 hours, Amazon should start accepting your requests and you should no longer experience that error.

The third case is when you hit your daily limit and you have to wait 12-24 hours. I advise you to decrease the number of daily requests and gradually increase them to understand what your limit is and then adjust accordingly. Each affiliate account has a request limit based on the number of sales made. The more purchases you make from your affiliate account, the more requests you will be able to make.

The fourth and final case occurs if you already make sales but the error message keeps appearing. In this case, you should contact Amazon directly and ask for clarification. There may be a technical problem preventing it from working properly.